# setting featured image is not working while running script in background, works when running that script from browser

Tags: post-thumbnails, cron, scripts, images

I have creted a script which will fetch content from one of my site and automatically create new post in my wordpress blog.

When I am running that script from browser, its working really cool! post is being created, intended image is being set as featured image but when I am trying to run it from background or as a cron job, post is being created, published but the featured image is not being set.

Please suggest me the proper solution. Here is my code to set the featured image.

```
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$attachment = array(
        'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($post_title)),
        'post_content' => 'just xyz',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id);
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
if( $featured )
{
    set_post_thumbnail($parent_post_id, $attach_id);
}
```

Additional info if it can help you in finding the problem. `wp_get_attachment_image` was not even working exactly after attaching image and executing above code. It was returning empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh Sorry, It was my mistake! It was caching problem.

Whoever facing such problems, just try to disable Database Cache(of Total Cache) plugin.
This caching is now pre-inistalled in all your new wordpress installation.